# Can't Select Manipulators in Edit Mode

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, 3d-manipulator

I'm trying to edit a mesh in Blender, but I can't select my manipulators in Edit Mode. They work perfectly fine in Object Mode, but in Edit Mode, it'll just make a border select when I try to click and drag them. I've changed my keyboard shortcuts to Maya, so I can't edit my mesh without the manipulators.

Select with Left is enabled and my selection mode in the System tab is set to OpenGL Select. I've increased the size of my handles to make them big enough to select, but doing this didn't help. Can anyone offer suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: keep ur cursor in 3d window and press ctrl+space its toggle key

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem isn't that the manipulator won't show up. It's that it shows up and I can't click on it while in Edit Mode.

Comment: Setting "Selection" in User Preferences System Tab from "Auto" to "OpenGL Select" or u can reset doing load factory setting

Comment: I've already set my Selection mode to OpenGL Select. I haven't tried resetting yet, but I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I reset to factory settings and I found the problem. Apparently some of the changes I made to the default Maya shortcuts were in conflict with each other, which was causing the error. I've reset to the default Maya shortcuts.